# Xcode project with Phonegap as subproject

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, cordova

Can i have this kind of set up?

I want to create a normal xcode project and just add the Cordovalib.xcodeproj to the xcode project?

Just like this one. http://mobiledan.net/2012/05/02/compile-phonegap-source-code-in-your-ios-phonegap-project/

But instead of creating a Cordova project from the start I will create a normal and standard Xcode Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, it has been available for a long time, I think since phonegap 1.5 on iOS. It's called cleaver.

To see how to use and configure, follow this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS) (for phonegap 2.1), in other versions it can be a bit different, and the steps were included in a pdf inside the `.dmg` of phonegap installation

Comment: do you have any other tutorials which uses cleaver? I can't seem to display my index.html as startPage

Comment: for phonegap 2.1 just the documentation, sorry.